# ¿Qué es considerado una sentencia en PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

El título, estoy actualmente estudiando y realizando ejercicios con Oracle PL/SQL y hasta ahora había trabajado perfectamente. Pero me surgió una duda debido a que un comentario en un documento el cuál estoy viendo dice lo siguiente.

> El NOMBRE DE USUARIO y CLAVE se DEBERÁN generar en sentencias PL/SQL,
> NO en la(s) sentencia(s) SELECT del bloque. Esto significa que, en
> cuando corresponda, DEBERÁ usar Estructura de Control Condicional para
> poder asignar valores como, por ejemplo, para la clave que se deberán
> obtener las dos letras en minúsculas del apellido del empleado de
> acuerdo a su estado civil.

Para más contexto, daré lo siguiente, insisto, no necesito código, más alguien que pueda aclarar mi duda al respecto para comprender bien qué debería hacer.

> Nombre de usuario será la unión de:
>
> - La primera letra de su estado civil en minúscula
> - Las tres primeras letras del primer nombre del empleado
> - El largo de su primer nombre
> - Un ASTERISCO
> - El último dígito de su sueldo base
> - El dígito verificador del run del empleado
> - Los años que lleva trabajando en la empresa.
> - Si el empleado lleva menos de 10 años trabajando en TRUCK RENTAL, se agrega además una X.

No colocaré lo que necesita la clave debido a que como comenté, sólo necesito una aclaración, alguien que logre interpretar este documento de la forma en que crea "correcta". Y a esto viene el título ¿Qué se considera una sentencia PL/SQL? ¿Qué diferencia hay entre un SELECT que guarda la información en variables con la clausula INTO y no un SELECT de bloque?

Answer (score 0):

PL/SQL (Procedural Language/Structured Query Language) es un lenguaje de programación incrustado en Oracle, que soporta todas las consultas (SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, CREATE, etc.), ya que la manipulación de datos que se usa es la misma que en SQL, pero además incluye:

- El manejo de variables.
- Estructuras modulares.
- Estructuras de control de flujo y toma de decisiones.
- Control de excepciones.

La estructura de bloque es una de las bases de PL/SQL, que se ejecuta a través de estructura en la que pueden distinguirse tres partes diferentes, que incluyen una palabra clave:

```
[DECLARE]
<declaration statements>;
[BEGIN]
<Execution statements>;
[EXCEPTION]
<Exception statements>;
END;
```

1. La parte declarativa en la que se declaran todas las constantes y variables que se usarán durante la ejecución del proceso. Comienza con la palabra **DECLARE**.
2. La parte de ejecución que incluye las instrucciones a llevar ejecutar en el bloque PL/SQL. Es la única obligatoria. Comienza con **BEGIN** y finaliza con **END**.
3. La parte de excepciones. Las excepciones permiten detectar y gestionar errores durante la ejecución del proceso.
   Comienza con la palabra **EXCEPTION**.

En un entorno de base de datos los programadores pueden construir bloques PL/SQL para utilizarlos como procedimientos o funciones, o bien pueden escribir estos bloques como parte de scripts.
Los programas o paquetes de PL/SQL se pueden almacenar en la base de datos como otro objeto, y todos los usuarios que estén autorizados tienen acceso a estos paquetes. Los programas se ejecutan en el servidor para ahorrar recursos a los clientes.

[Aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/a_samps.htm) puedes ver varios ejemplos de sentencias con PL/SQL y en [este link](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/pl-sql-tutorial/) mucha más información sobre PL/SQL.